# Appinventor : Property setter was expecting a com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.ImageSprite component but got a String instead

Tags: app-inventor

i'm currently working on a Naughts and Crosses game in MIT App Inventor 2, and have run into the error in the title, i believe i've narrowed it down to a specific block of my code (the easyBot procedure) but i cannot isolate the issue from there, i have provided source code for perusal, can anyone find the issue here?

source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/plw8has3df47diw/XOXOXOXO_checkpoint1.aia?dl=0

> error : Property setter was expecting a com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.ImageSprite component but got a String instead

Comment: I've managed to resolve the problem myself, in the Easybot procedure, i was changing the chosenSprite variable with a value from the wrong list, this has prevented the runtime error from happening.

Comment: great that you found the solution... and next time you might want to provide a screenshot of you relevant blocks instead of the complete source...than you...